# C++ Ball Bouncing in the rhombus

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, gdi+, bounce

I made a simple ball bouncing program with VC++.
the goal of this program is that ball must bounce in the rhombus. it cannot go out of rhombus.

It seems that it runs successfully, but in the left and right corner, it stuck.
How to resolve this problem? I think the condition of equlation is duplicated when the ball is going to left and right corner...
Can you suggest other algorithm for solve this problem?

 i tried to make this problem like 
`while(!isInside(getNextPos(circle))) { updateDirectionVector(circle); }`
but I cannot do like this because a random value has changed in everytime. (Used Timer to repeat)

This is algorithm of this program which is worked except at the corner.

```
up:
while(1) goDownSideCircle;
if(StuckOnDownSide) goto down;
down:
while(1) goUpSideCircle;
if(StuckOnUpSide) goto up;
```

Comment: Is your code really indented like this? If yes, then I am afraid you are out of luck... or is this because of pasting here?

Comment: are you sure you are not trying to implement a new linux kernel in here :-)
by the way, goto keyword is depreciated. avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: To make it easier for those trying to read and understand your code you should format it so that it doesn't need to be scrolled horizontally. Also, replace all numerical constants with proper descriptively named constants and combine results of calculations into appropriately named variables.

Comment: For example, there is no reason why `50*(float) Math::Cos(j)` should be repeated 4 times in two lines of code. Same goes for `Sin(j)`.

Comment: Looking at the latest edit, are you sure `goXXXSideCircle` and the subsequent `if(...)` do not belong in the same scope? As it is, there is no point in the `goto down;` statement - the program flow will always proceed to the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.

 Solved Algorithm:

```
    RandValue;
    while(1){
    DrawCircle(Center_X,Center_Y);
    Center_X+=Rand_X; Center_Y+=Rand_Y;
    check=false;
    Check_X=Center_X; Check_Y=Center_Y;
    while(BorderCheck){
    RandValue;
    Check_X+=Rand_X; Check_Y+=Rand_Y;
    check=true;}
    if(check){
    Center_X=Check_X; Center_Y=Check_Y;}}
```